# Vuetify Outlined text field label position is wrong when active

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `"@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3"` for my project. Everything was working fine. Recently I am having a problem on `outlined` text-field or select. When active label staying under the border. I am not exactly sure how it came to this, or how I can fix this.

I am providing sample on how I am implementing them.

```
  <v-col md="6" sm="12" cols="12" class="colClassTwo no-limit">
    <h2>Send Us A Message</h2>
    <div class="formDiv">
      <div class="formClassDiv">
        <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation class="formClass">
          <v-text-field
            label="Your Name"
            color="#fb6331"
            background-color="#fff"
            outlined
            v-model="data.name"
            :rules="[rules.required]"
          ></v-text-field>

          <v-text-field
            label="Your Email"
            color="#fb6331"
            background-color="#fff"
            outlined
            v-model="data.email"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.email]"
          ></v-text-field>

          <v-text-field
            label="Your Contact"
            color="#fb6331"
            background-color="#fff"
            outlined
            :rules="[rules.required]"
            v-model="data.phone"
          ></v-text-field>

          <v-text-field
            label="Your Message (Optional)"
            color="#fb6331"
            background-color="#fff"
            outlined
            v-model="data.currentVendor"
          ></v-text-field>

          <div style="text-align: center">
            <a @click="handleClick" class="btn__gradient-fill"
              ><span class="btn-text"
                ><p class="text-gradient mb-0">Submit</p></span
              ></a
            >
          </div>
        </v-form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-col>
```

[image: outlined textfield]

Any suggestion would be welcomed

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: The issue is likely due to your own custom input styles, so we'll need to see a reproduction to be able to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Can you check in this link? http://prwire.dhrubokisl.xyz/contact

Comment: The code snippet on it's own works as expected. Your link is throwing a 502 (it was working a little earlier) Please create a codepen if you can. One UX issue I would point out is that the form starts out invalid, which might cause the error state to not be clear to the user .

Comment: Link is redeployed. Will work now

Comment: Are you using a for loop to create the text fields? Maybe dynamic label length can't be calculated and the border doesn't know how wide the gap should be. But, even when the label is an empty string, there should be a small openings visible on the top border. Could there be any inherited overriding styles for input borders?

On the other hand, the textfield looks a little off to me. The page background is visible around the input's white background (noticeable around email and message fields). When the label moves, the position is slightly lower than it should be: centred on the border.

Comment: Not using loops. Something changed globally. Not even a new text-field created with no css and just outlined produce this ui

Comment: Hi, did you fixed fix it? it's happening the same to me, but I don't find a way to solve it